# SharePoint List item attachments fail when the file size is beyond 900KB?

Tags: sharepoint-server, item-attachment

We have a SharePoint 2016 on-premise site where the list item attachments fails to accept files above ~ 900kb, we tried smaller files like 200-300kb it works.
However the document library except all larger files, the problem is with only List item attachments. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Open the browser console window and check for any errors ? May be you will able to identify the error.

Comment: Last I checked, list item attachments max size was 2GB. As Jefin noted, take a look at the browser console window as well as ULS on the SharePoint Server side.

Comment: Hi, I noticed no errors in the browser console. also, i found that the attachments work fine on the Internet explorer. I tried a file of 8mb it worked on IE, but doesnt work on Edge/Chrome.